# Converting a firebase snapshot to array recursively not working correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, recursion, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure on my firebase database:

[image]

I need to get an array of all the data with *a special structure*. This is how I do it:

```
const isObject = obj => {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]' ? true : false;
};

function snapshotToArray(snapshot) {
    var returnArr = [];

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var item = childSnapshot.val();
        item.key = childSnapshot.key;

        returnArr.push(item);

        if (isObject(item)){
            returnArr = returnArr.concat(snapshotToArray(childSnapshot));
        }

    });

    return returnArr;
};
```

And call it:

```
snapshotToArray(snapshot); // 'snapshot' is the data from database in a snapshot format
```

Getting:

```
[ { 'Diciembre-2018': { '-LJV5UxepDNSR5yUCDbf': [Object] },
    'Julio-2018': { '-LJUt8yTjpK3oq2wRd_g': [Object] },
    key: '2018' },
  { '-LJV5UxepDNSR5yUCDbf':
     { pin: 'mi-pin-dic',
       timestamp: 'Thu Aug 09 2018 13:11:39 GMT-0600 (GMT-06:00)' },
    key: 'Diciembre-2018' },
  { pin: 'mi-pin-dic',
    timestamp: 'Thu Aug 09 2018 13:11:39 GMT-0600 (GMT-06:00)',
    key: '-LJV5UxepDNSR5yUCDbf' },
  'mi-pin-dic',
  'Thu Aug 09 2018 13:11:39 GMT-0600 (GMT-06:00)',
  { '-LJUt8yTjpK3oq2wRd_g':
     { pin: 'mi-pin-julio',
       timestamp: 'Thu Aug 09 2018 12:13:21 GMT-0600 (GMT-06:00)' },
    key: 'Julio-2018' },
  { pin: 'mi-pin-julio',
    timestamp: 'Thu Aug 09 2018 12:13:21 GMT-0600 (GMT-06:00)',
    key: '-LJUt8yTjpK3oq2wRd_g' },
  'mi-pin-julio',
  'Thu Aug 09 2018 12:13:21 GMT-0600 (GMT-06:00)' ]
```

But as you can see, in the 3rd and 5th iteration it gets an extra data:

```
'mi-pin-dic',
  'Thu Aug 09 2018 13:11:39 GMT-0600 (GMT-06:00)',

'mi-pin-julio',
  'Thu Aug 09 2018 12:13:21 GMT-0600 (GMT-06:00)'
```

**My question:**

How can I avoid this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like pin and timestamp are also classified as object.

Comment: I would try isObject(childSnapshot.val()) instead of isObject(item).

Comment: I tried your idea, and does not work :(

Comment: Could you print out the type of childSnapshot.val() for each iteration by using Object.prototype.toString.call(childSnapshot.val())?

Comment: I moved your code `isObject(childSnapshot.val())` exaclty after the `foreach`, and it's working !

Comment: What I speculate is that when you say item.key = ..., you turn childSnapshot.val() into a object. This is why checking isObject(childSnapshot.val()) beforehand works.